# How can I create this specific grid design in html/css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Ok, so I’ve got a css grid of icons, but I want to make a divider between all the cells that kinda gets lower opacity towards the edges, like an airbrush. However, I also want the cells themselves to remain transparent so that the pattern in the background is still visible behind it, so I can’t just make a blurry blob and put the grid on top of it with a small gap size. I drew a quick mock-up to demonstrate what I’m talking about.

Specifically, I'm looking for how to make gradient borders for css grid. Thanks in advance for any help!

[image: The target design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good guide about gradient borders. If you're doing it exact the same way like in this guide, you'll lose transparency on your items. However you can consider "faking" the borders by using `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements and use gradients in here.

https://css-tricks.com/gradient-borders-in-css/

I created an example with `::before` and `::absolute` here:

https://codepen.io/max-crcl/pen/ExOGdvM